# Navbar on the header?

Tags: html, css, nav

I tried to put a navbar on the header but no success. I did search on this site but I couldn't find the answer.

EDITED: added markup html.

[image: Here the picture]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>"New York City"</title>
 <meta charset="uft-8">
 <style>


@font-face {
    font-family: Breamcatcher; src: url('Breamcatcher.ttf'); 
}

body {
    background: url("New York City Night.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
}

#header {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    /*Opacity start*/
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and eariler */
    /*Opacity end*/
    font-family: Breamcatcher, san-serif;
    font-size: 500%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0; 
}

span.header2 {
    margin: auto;
    color: orange;
    font-size: 185%; 
} 

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="header"><span class="header2"> New York City </span></div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

How do I put it on the header? Also how do I add the logo? Thank you!

[image: Here the picture]

Comment: have any html to post?

Comment: Share your markup HTML too

Comment: a link to your site if it is published

Comment: You can try to put the navbar html code in you header div/tag. than set the position of the navbar to fixed and bottom:0px and left:0px;

Comment: Where's the HTML for the navbar?

Comment: Still not seeing the HTML or CSS for the navbar after your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll attempt to help you with this even though you haven't really given us much information to go off.

Basically, you're going to want to add an unordered list into the header to represent your links. That's not the only way to add a navigation menu, but it is one of the most common ways. You can do that like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <span class="header2">New York City</span>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Then you need to add some CSS so that the `list items` display in a single horizontal line like this:

```
nav ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

You can see an example(without the background image) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7xsy5khm/). From there you can add some more CSS so that it looks the way you want.

You also mentioned wanting to add a logo, did you mean in addition to the `span` you currently have in the header? I would consider the "New York City" `span` to be the "logo." Give us some more code/details if you would like further help.

One last thing, you have quotation marks around "New York City" in the `title` tag. These quotation marks are not necessary unless you intended for them to be there.